# What happens if we upgrade a program or software that is in use in Debian-derived distributions?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, debian

I am wondering about what is happening when we upgrade a package that contains some files which is currently in use.

Why the old program still works well while the files in the File System has already been changed? What is the mechanism that prevents the program from crashing when something like "aptitude upgrade" is running?

In addition, how can I change a file safely while it is still in use?

I've googled a while but answers seem to be off-topic.

Comment: 'Cause Linux is not Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A running executable (or `mmap`-ed file) is viewed from the kernel as an [inode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode).

I would guess that package managers (e.g. `dpkg` invoked by `apt-get`) are using [rename(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) or [unlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html), so the currently running executable stays the same inode.

Recall that an inode is removed on the file system -i.e. on the disk- only when it has no references (neither from some directory; nor from the kernel as an opened file descriptor or running executable or  [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)-ed file).

BTW, when you upgrade `libc` the packaging system offers you to restart some daemons...

Answer (score 3):

If the running program has an open filehandle (e.g. to the libraries or executable) that's updated, the open file is not actually reclaimed from the filesystem until after the file handle is released.

This is the same mechanism that allows you to have an "anonymous" temporary file by creating a file, and immediately unlinking it... you can still read/write to the unlinked file, but nobody else can see or access the file.